# unix: merge files based on column value

Tags: bash, unix, merge

I have two files, that look like this:

File 1 (2 columns):

```
ID1 123
ID2 234
ID3 232
ID4 344
...
```

File 2 (>1 million columns)

```
ID2 A C ...
ID3 G T ...
ID1 C T ...
ID4 A C ... 
...
```

I want to add the values from column 2 of file 1 based on the ID to file 2 as the second column. So the merged file should look like this:

```
ID2 234 A C ...
ID3 232 G T ...
ID1 123 C T ...
ID4 344 A C ... 
...
```

So exactly the same as file 2 (same order of rows), but with the added 2nd column. The IDs are the values of the first column (present in both files). File 1 has more rows/IDs than file 2. All IDs from file 2 are in file 1, but not all IDs from file 1 are in file 2.

Does anyone know how to do this under unix/bash? Many thanks!

Comment: How many rows are there? (Is it feasible to load all of file 1 into memory?)

Comment: File 1 has close to 4 million rows, file 2 has tens of thousands to hundreds of thousands of rows (I actually have several files in the format of file 2, so I have to do this multiple times (= for each file))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
ID1 123 C T ...
ID2 234 A C ...
ID3 232 G T ...
ID4 344 A C ...
```

If you want keep the order of `file2`

```
$ join -1 1 -2 2 <(sort file1) <(cat -n file2 | sort -k2,2) | sort -k3,3n | cut -d' ' -f1-2,4-
ID2 234 A C ...
ID3 232 G T ...
ID1 123 C T ...
ID4 344 A C ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, except that for some reason he starts a new line after each value of the added second column... (so each row is now 2 rows, with the second row starting at "C T ...") Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @Abdel, I guess it is because there is an extra \r at the end of the line. If you use dos2unix to "process" file1 first to remove those \r, then it should be OK.

Comment: After double checking, he didn't do it for all rows unfortunately... The merged file consists of less rows than the original file 2 (about 5000 rows less). And this is not because there are IDs missing in file 1 that are in file 2 (I checked it manually in SPSS, and there are only 55 that should be missing instead of 5000)... any idea how this might happen? Btw, I also get the message "join: file 1 is not in sorted order" during the process.. could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @Abdel, yes, `join` *requires* sorted files.

Comment: But the commands that was suggested includes sorting right? I used exactly this command: $ join -1 1 -2 2 <(sort file1) <(cat -n file2 | sort -k2,2) | sort -k3,3n | cut -d' ' -f1-2,4-

Comment: You should run this command on a smaller dataset to make sure it's OK.

Comment: I think it has something to do with "sort -k2,2" and "sort -k3,3n" in your command (not exactly sure how that works). My IDs actually look like this: rs11089130. They all start with "rs" and then a bunch of nrs (the nr of nrs varies). I used "ÏD1" "ID2" in the example for convenience, and I think you incorporated that format in your command?