# Joining two files based on the first columns and preserving order

Tags: unix

How can I join two files based on their first columns and preserving the order from the second file..

File 1:

```
ID1 123
ID2 234
ID3 232
ID4 344
ID5 345
ID6 867
```

File 2

```
ID2 A C
ID3 G T
ID1 C T
ID4 A C
...
```

So the merged file should look like this:

```
ID2 234 A C 
ID3 232 G T 
ID1 123 C T 
ID4 344 A C 
...
```

The `IDs` are the values of the first column (present in both files). File 1 has more rows/IDs than file 2. 
All `ID`s from file 2 are in file 1, but not all `ID`s from file 1 are in file 2

Comment: possible duplicate of [unix: merge files based on column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806711/unix-merge-files-based-on-column-value)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$2; next } $1 in a { print $1, a[$1], $2, $3 }' file1 file2
```

Results:

```
ID2 234 A C
ID3 232 G T
ID1 123 C T
ID4 344 A C
```

Comment: +1 nice oneliner. But watch out for memory consumption if file1 is too big.

Answer (score 2):

Using `join`:

```
$ join file1.txt file2.txt

ID1 123 C T
ID2 234 A C
ID3 232 G T
ID4 344 A C
```

**Note**: the files need to be sorted first which doesn't keep the order of file2.txt but this *cleanest* way if you don't care about that.

Pre-sort files inplace first: `sort file1.txt -o file1.txt; sort file2.txt -o file2.txt`

Do the join: `join file1.txt file2.txt`

In general you could `join file1.txt file.txt | sort` and sort on some criteria but in this case `file2.txt` isn't sorted by any column/criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You read the two files line by line and extract the lines tokens by means of a regex. The extracted tokens are stored inside associative array, using the first token as key. In a second step you can loop through all available keys and construct output lines from the values stored inside the arrays.

An example implementation in php, for demonstration purposes only. So no error checking done, and probably the patterns will have to be adapted to your needs. The same can obviously be done in all other languages. I just chose php because it is very easy to read:

```
<?php
$input_file[1]=fopen('/path/input1.list','r');
$input_file[2]=fopen('/path/input2.list','r');

# read input files line by line
foreach ($input_file as $input){
    while (!feof($input)){
        $tokens=array();
        preg_match('/^(ID[0-9]+) (.+)$/',trim(fread($input)),$tokens);
        $list[$i][$tokens[1]]=$tokens[2];
   } 
}

# construct output lines:
$output_file=fopen('/path/output.list','w');
foreach ($list[1] as $key=>$val){
    $line=sprintf("%s %s%s\n", $key, $val, 
                  array_key_exists($key,$list[2])?' '.$list[2][$key]:'' );
    fwrite($output_file,$line);
}

# some house keeping
fclose($input_file[1]);
fclose($input_file[2]);
fclose($output_file);

?>
```

( Please note that I did not check this, I just wrote this down. It is meant to be a starting point, not ready-to-use )