# fetch a list of items from a table without using database software

Tags: python, sql, linux, bash, bioinformatics

I want to do some simple database operations on a table without bothering with a database software, e.g., I can use the "filo" package from GitHub to do something similar to "groupby" function. I wonder is there something similar to achieve some simple "join" function?  Or can I do it with Python or Bash? Specifically, I have a table like:

```
Col5a2  NM_007737   chr1    -   45447828    45447829
Slc40a1 NM_016917   chr1    -   45870140    45870141
Gm3852  NM_001177356    chr1    -   45956809    45956810
Slc39a10    NM_172653   chr1    -   46798055    46798056
Obfc2a  NM_028696   chr1    -   51422944    51422945
Myo1b   NM_001161817,NM_010863  chr1    -   51860519    51860520
.
.
.
```

And I have a list

```
Slc40a1
Myo1b
Col5a2
Obfc2a
.
.
.
```

I want to fetch the items in the list from the table, so that I will get:

```
Slc39a10    NM_172653   chr1    -   46798055    46798056
Myo1b   NM_001161817,NM_010863  chr1    -   51860519    51860520
Col5a2  NM_007737   chr1    -   45447828    45447829
Obfc2a  NM_028696   chr1    -   51422944    51422945
.
.
.
```

Comment: sqlite3 comes builtin to python 3... why wouldnt you use it?

Comment: The best thing to simulate SQL Joins is using... SQL Joins... as the ones you can get in sqllite, for instance **:)**

Comment: It's really a big time-saver.

Comment: it is a really big time saver to use tools that already provide the functionality you want without reinventing the wheel ...

Comment: It seems I'd better learn some sqllite to make my life easier in the future. I know nothing about it. But I do want to have a quick solution with Python or shell script right now.

Comment: Thanks! @locojay How does "pandas and pytables" compare with sqllite? What is the major difference?

Comment: Do people still use perl for generic text file processing?

Comment: mainly speed : http://www.pytables.org/docs/SciPy04.pdf

Comment: I still use lots of Perl scripts from other people. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: 1. Read about the `fgrep` cmd. `fgrep -f list data` may be all you need. 2. OR  so your sample data/table is in a text file? If so, if you can change to tab-delimted data, look at the unix `join` command.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$0; next } $1 in a { print a[$1] }' table list
```

or with formatting:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$0; next } $1 in a { print a[$1] }' table list | column -t
```

Results:

```
Slc40a1  NM_016917               chr1  -  45870140  45870141
Myo1b    NM_001161817,NM_010863  chr1  -  51860519  51860520
Col5a2   NM_007737               chr1  -  45447828  45447829
Obfc2a   NM_028696               chr1  -  51422944  51422945
```

Explanation:

> 'FNR==NR { ... }' is a conditional that is only true for the first file in the argument list.
>
> > So for each line in the file called 'table', the first column ($1) is added to an array (called 'a') and this is assigned the value of the whole line ($0). 'next' then skips to remainder of the code and jumps to the next line of input, until all lines in the 'table' file have been processed.
>
> '$1 in a' is another conditional.
>
> > This is asking if column one of the 'list' file is a key in the array. If it is, then print out the value of column one that we just stored in the array (a[$1]).

Comment: I have tested the script, it works perfectly! @steve Could you please explain the meaning of "{ a[$1]=$0; next } $1 in a { print a[$1] }" a little bit?

Comment: @Runner: I've added a bit of an explanation. Please let me know if I haven't added enough detail or if more clarification is needed. HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Awk is so powerful.

Comment: I have one more question about this answer. Is this method case sensitive, if it is, can I make it case insensitive? Sorry that I know nothing about AWK. I do want to learn some AWK, please give me some good link for learning AWK if you know any.Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Runner: `awk` is naturally case sensitive. You can turn off case sensitivity, using a variable called `IGNORECASE`. When set to a non-zero value, pattern matching can be completed case-insensitively. See the man page. However, the value of `IGNORECASE` has no effect on array subscripting. The workaround is to use `tolower()`. In your case, try: `awk 'FNR==NR { a[tolower($1)]=$0; next } tolower($1) in a { print a[tolower($1)] }' table list | column -t`. When I started learning `awk`, I started [here](http://bashshell.net/stream-filtering-utilities/exercise-1-learning-awk-basics/). HTH.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed accomplish this with two standard unix tools, `join(1)` and `sort(1)`:

```
$ join <(sort table) <(sort list)

Col5a2 NM_007737 chr1 - 45447828 45447829
Myo1b NM_001161817,NM_010863 chr1 - 51860519 51860520
Obfc2a NM_028696 chr1 - 51422944 51422945
Slc40a1 NM_016917 chr1 - 45870140 45870141
```

The call to `sort` is needed because (from [join man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join)):

> Important: FILE1 and FILE2 must be sorted on the join fields. E.g., use 'sort -k 1b,1' if 'join' has no options. Note, comparisons honor the rules specified by 'LC_COLLATE'. If the input is not sorted and some lines cannot be joined, a warning message will be given.

**Update:** A solution inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9806738/295262), keeping order:

```
$ join -1 2 <(cat -n list | sort -k2,2) <(sort table) | sort -nk2,2 | cut -d\  -f1,3-
```

Comment: amazing! But can I use "cat" instead of "sort"? I want to keep the order in the list.@Linus G Thiel

Comment: I just read the man of join. It seems that I can simply use "join table list". What is the difference between "join table list" and "join<(sort table)<(sort list)". Sorry for my ignorance.@Linus G Thiel

Comment: Unfortunately, the files need to be sorted -- ergo the call to `sort`. I don't know if you can somehow reorder it according to the list, I'll try and think about it.

Comment: You should take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9806738/295262), it's a clever solution (prefixing the list with linenumbers, and sorting the data back on that after joining).

Answer (score 1):

If you're only doing very simple lookups by the first column of your table, a python `dict` is probably enough of a data structure.

Build it like this:

```
table = {}
with open(table_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split()
        table[row[0]] = row
```

You can then do your "join" against this dictionary using a list comprehension:

```
results = [table[key] for key in keys_list]
```

Or if your second list is also a data file, you can do this instead:

```
with open(second_file) as f:
    results = [table[line.strip] for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
data = []
with open("file1.txt") as f:  #the data file
   for row in f:
      data.append(row.split())
with open("file2.txt") as f:  #the keys file
   keys = map(str.strip,f.readlines())
np_data = np.array(data,np.str)
mask = np.in1d(np_data[:,0],keys)
print np_data[mask]
```

thats how id do it if i really didnt want to use a database

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas which work like a database to "select" and pivot. This is an example that works:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'Col5a2'  : ['NM_007737',    '-',         'chr1', 45447828, 45447829],
        'Slc40a1' : ['NM_016917',    '-',         'chr1', 45870140, 45870141],
        'Gm3852'  : ['NM_001177356', '-',         'chr1', 45956809, 45956810],
        'Slc39a10': ['NM_172653',    '-',         'chr1', 46798055, 46798056],
        'Obfc2a'  : ['NM_028696',    '-',         'chr1', 51422944, 51422945],
        'Myo1b'   : ['NM_001161817', 'NM_010863', 'chr1', 51860519, 51860520],
    })
data.get(['Slc40a1', 'Myo1b', 'Col5a2', 'Obfc2a'])

# Output:

     Slc40a1         Myo1b     Col5a2     Obfc2a
0  NM_016917  NM_001161817  NM_007737  NM_028696
1          -     NM_010863          -          -
2       chr1          chr1       chr1       chr1
3   45870140      51860519   45447828   51422944
4   45870141      51860520   45447829   51422945
```