# Matching data in separate files

Tags: awk

I've seem several questions of this type and have truly tried to work this out on my own without success.

I have two files of data; I want to compare their first fields and print the line from the second file next to the matching entry from the first file in an output file. It is important to maintain the list order in file 1, including the lines with no matches. The files are tab separated values but I can change them if required (although commas are in use in the data).

file1.txt

```
37600
39219
32887
01262
69241
00361
34180
42385
69245
```

file2.txt

```
37600       GEAR PUMP   1
32887       MOTOR, 480V 1
34180       BRACKET 2
00361       WASHER  4
42385       SCREW       8
```

Desired Output file

```
37600       GEAR PUMP   1
39219
32887       MOTOR, 480V 1
01262
69241
00361       WASHER  4
34180       BRACKET 2
42385       SCREW       8
69245
```

This is my best effort so far but it results in an empty file.

```
awk NR==NFR{a[$1];next}$1 in a {print $0} file1.txt file2.txt > outfile.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the `42385` line in your output, why the 2nd column is empty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unix: merge files based on column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806711/unix-merge-files-based-on-column-value)

Comment: @Kent. Typo fixed. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: Where did this number `69245` go? Should it be in your output example?

Comment: @Jotne. Yes, it should be in the output. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, this `awk` should do.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} a[$0] {$0=a[$0]}1' file2 file1
37600       GEAR PUMP   1
39219
32887       MOTOR, 480V 1
01262
69241
00361       WASHER  4
34180       BRACKET 2
42385       SCREW       8
69245
```

I stores the `file2` in array with `$1` as an index.
If value in `file1` is found in array, set this as `$0` and print all out.

---

You could write this too, to mark that its column `#1` that should be compared:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} a[$1] {$0=a[$1]}1' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [join](http://www.albany.edu/~ig4895/join.htm):

```
join -1 2 -2 1 -a1 <(cat -n file1.txt | sort -k2,2) <(sort file2.txt) | sort -k2 | cut --complement -d" " -f2

37600 GEAR PUMP 1
39219
32887 MOTOR, 480V 1
01262
69241
00361 WASHER 4
34180 BRACKET 2
42385 SCREW 8
69245
```

As per @devnul's suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Hi would like all the line that does not match to be printed too. Se OPs requested output.

Comment: No need to be sorry :)

Comment: OP said that the order of file 1 needs to be maintained.

Comment: You should remove the number added.  Maybe for this `awk` with one single command is better..