# sorting text file by order listed in other file

Tags: linux, sorting, text

I would need to sort space separated text file which looks something like this:

```
rs4771122 1.983 0.998 1.998 1.990 0.998 0.988 1.000 1.984 0.001 1.998 1.996  
rs1333026 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000  
rs11847697 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000  
rs10150332 1.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 1.000 1.000 0.975 0.000 1.000  
etc.
```

It should be sorted by first column according to the order listed in separate text file containing all the values in first column. Second file looks like this:

```
rs1333026  
rs11847697  
rs4771122  
rs10150332
etc.
```

And output should look like this:

```
rs1333026 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000  
rs11847697 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000  
rs4771122 1.983 0.998 1.998 1.990 0.998 0.988 1.000 1.984 0.001 1.998 1.996  
rs10150332 1.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 1.000 1.000 0.975 0.000 1.000
etc.
```

Is there a way to use sort command similarly to grep with -f flag in order to obtain this?

Thank you.

Comment: is first column having unique values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding contents of one file into another file in unix shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059422/finding-contents-of-one-file-into-another-file-in-unix-shell-script)

Comment: Not really, @Kami , see in this case the order matters.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9806738/701750

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the second file and keep `grep`ing each line in the first file.

Like this, for example:

```
while read line
do
   grep -wF "$line" f1
done < f2
```

#### Explanation

- `grep -w` matches full words.
- `grep -F` matches fixed strings, so no regex.

#### Test

```
$ while read line; do grep "$line" f1; done < f2
rs1333026 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000  
rs11847697 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000  
rs4771122 1.983 0.998 1.998 1.990 0.998 0.988 1.000 1.984 0.001 1.998 1.996  
rs10150332 1.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 1.000 1.000 0.975 0.000 1.000
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked on test files I provided, but for reason I can't see right now because I'm exhausted it doesn't work on real files. It works until 10th line of 13 lines, then skips one, and ads additional 12 in order can't decipher. I'm sure the problem is in files, I just can't see it.

Comment: I see it now. I expected that second file contains only values listed in first column of first file. It has one additional value. I will just have to check all files (there are more than two pairs) prior to sorting. Thank you again.

Comment: @ludiklobucar in case you have more than one file, you can replace `< f2` with `< <(cat f2 f3)` or whatever files you have. Make sure you do not have extra spaces also (in case, you can remove the `-w` and `-F` options and just use `grep "$line" f1`.

Comment: Yes, it works now, it was that unfortunate extra value that made the mess. And thank you for suggestion to mark the answer, I was not aware of that option.